# i have some string like 220.00 and i remove the .00 from it

Tags: php, decimal

> i have some string like 220.00 and i remove the .00 from it.

```
 $values[] = array(
                                "filter_code"=>(string)reset($priceArr),
                                "filter_value"=>(string)end($priceArr)
                            );
```

> the out put is

```
{
                    "filter_code": "1.00",
                    "filter_value": "825.00"
                },
                {
                    "filter_code": "1.00",
                    "filter_value": "825.00"
                },
```

> so how can i remove the .00 from it

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are always integers (aways end in .00) you can round them:

```
var_dump(round('125.00')); // float(125)
```

Or just cast to int:

```
var_dump((int)'125.00'); // int(125)
```

If those are prices like 12.99, but sometimes it is .00 you can replace .00 with empty string:

```
var_dump(str_replace('.00', '', '125.00')); // string(3) "125"
var_dump(str_replace('.00', '', '125.99')); // string(6) "125.99"
```

Or with regex to replace .00 at the end with empty string:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/.00$/', '', '125.00')); // string(3) "125"
var_dump(preg_replace('/.00$/', '', '125.99')); // string(6) "125.99"
```